# This tree is growing in my yard - central VA zone 7 anyone ID? No flowers so far

Tags: identification, trees

This tree is growing wild in my yard about 10 feet tall now. It looked a little like an apple but not when I pick leaves and compare. It grew quite fast and has not flowered yet where most other trees here are finished.

Any ideas what this could be?

I live in central VA (zone 7).

[image: closeup_green_tree]

Comment: If there are little apples, probably there were flowers. Look on the left, at 1/3 (from the top) of the image. These could be some not very visible flowers.

Comment: more photos please, I think I would like to know what this is? picture of flowers, fruit, does it drop its leaves in winter? some extra info too.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a Asimina triloba AKA Paw Paw Tree in the US and Canada.  (Not to be confused with a Carica papaya called a Pawpaw Tree in Australia.)   A.triloba is native to Eastern US and the very southern tip of Ontario, Canada.  It is a fruit bearing tree.  The fruit is often compared to the taste & texture of a banana.  It is not a commercial crop, because the fruit lacks any substantial shelf life.

It is small deciduous tree reaching on average 10 m (33') tall.  It spreads predominately by suckers.  It has a low fertility rate.  The spring blooming flowers have faint rotting meat smell that only attracts a few insects.  If the smell was stronger it would probably attract more pollinators.  Each tree may produce many flowers, but only a few fruit.  It can be hand pollinated if you want more fruit.

It prefers fertile soil.  A topdressing yearly of compost, leaf mold or both will be beneficial to the tree.  It is often found in lowlands at the edge of the forest with trees like Cornus florida or Cercis canadensis.  Supplemental watering maybe required during dry spells.